# Server connectivity validation through python codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest, python-sockets

I have a MySQL server hosted at a particular IP and port. Now, I need to validate this connectivity whether the server is up or down. Also this server uses a self-signed SSL certificate.

Does anyone have any reference python snippet that would comply this connectivity validation along with SSL certificate verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trye the same thing you'd do from a command line. E.g. when you ``telnet`server port`, then you get "connection refused" if a server is not listening on the given port, or a timeout if server:port is behind a firewall, or "No route to host" etc. For a successful connection you get something.

Self signed certs can't be validate, AFAIK, and this will work for ssl connections too.

```
import telnetlib

server_ip = '192.168.2.1'
server_port = 80
timeout = 5

conn_ok = False

try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(server_ip, server_port, timeout)
    conn_ok = True
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

tn.close()
```